# Error al integrar AdminLte 3.0.5 y bootstrap-datepicker en laravel 7, $(...).datepicker is not a function

Tags: jquery, laravel-7, adminlte, bootstrap-datepicker

Estoy tratando de integrar bootstrap-datepicker con la plantilla AdminLte en un pequeño proyecto en laravel 7, pero al referenciar al datepicker, me arroja el siguiente error en consola:

$(...).datepicker is not a function

Cuando se ingresa a la vista, el datepicker está deshabilitado. Cuando se selecciona SÍ en el Select, se habilita y es en ese momento que marca el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Leyendo la documentación de bootstrap-datepicker, dice que se debe incluir:

Bootstrap 2.0.4+
jQuery 1.7.1+

Como jquery ya está en la plantilla AdminLte, agregué Bootstrap, pero se modifica un poco la pantalla y el error persiste:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisando el tema, pienso que el error está en el orden de carga de las librerias js y css. Me parece que hay un conflicto en la secuencia en que se cargan las librerías de AdminLte y bootstrap-datepicker y las de bootstrap que necesita bootstrap-datepicker.

La verdad es que llevo un tiempo tratando de arreglar esto, pero no sé dónde estará el problema o si es problema del orden en que se referencian las librerías, cómo se debería hacer, pues cuando agregue otros componentes, tal vez se me presenten los mismos problemas.

Si alguien ha pasado por este problema y lo ha solucionado, o alguien sabe cómo resolverlo, estaré muy agradecido de la ayuda.

El de la vista es:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>PROYECTO</title>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('dist/js/adminlte.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css')}}">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="{{ asset('dist/css/adminlte.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Hasta aquí es de AdminLte 3.0.5 -->

    <!--Agregado para Datepicker-->        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script> 

    <!--Datepicker-->
    <script src="{{ asset('datePicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js') }}"></script>
    <link href="{{ asset('datePicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {     

            (function(){
                $('#calendarioActividad').attr("disabled",true); 
            }());

            $(document).on('change', '#actividad', function ()
            {
                if($('#actividad').val()==1){                       
                    $('#calendarioActividad').datepicker('setDate', null);
                    $('#calendarioActividad').attr("disabled",true);
                }else{
                    $('#calendarioActividad').attr("disabled",false);
                    $('#calendarioActividad').datepicker("setDate", new Date());
                }
            });

            $(document).on("click",'#calendarioActividad', function(){

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed">
    <div id="app">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <!-- Navbar -->
            <nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand navbar-white navbar-light">
                <!-- Left navbar links -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <!-- /.navbar OK-->

            <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
            <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
                <!-- Sidebar -->
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
                    <div class="info">
                        <a href="#" class="d-block">
                            @guest
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Iniciar Sesión') }}</a>
                            @else
                            {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                    document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                Cerrar Sesión
                            </a>
                            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST"
                                style="display: none;">
                                @csrf
                            </form>
                            @endguest
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!--</div>-->

                    <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
                    <nav class="mt-2">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu"
                            data-accordion="false">
                            <!-- OPCION FECHA -->
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="{{ url('solicitudes/fecha') }}" 
                                    class="{{ Request::is('solicitudes/fecha') ? 'nav-link active' : 'nav-link' }}">
                                    <i class="nav-icon fas fa-home"></i>
                                    <p>
                                        Fecha                                                                                                          
                                    </p>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
                </div>
            <!-- /.sidebar -->
            </aside>

            <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
                <div class="content-header">

                </div>
                <!-- /.content-header -->

                <!-- contenido -->
                <section class="content">
                    <div class="row container-fluid mt-1 justify-content-start">
                        <div class="col-6 align-self-end">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="act">REALIZACIÓN DE ACTIVIDAD</span>
                                </div>
                                <select id="actividad" name="actividad[]" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-info" title="Seleccione Opción">
                                    <option value="1">No</option>;
                                    <option value="2">Sí</option>;
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 align-self-end">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="fech">FECHA DE EJECUCIÓN</span>
                                </div>
                                <!-- PROBLEMA DE FECHA -->
                                <div class="input-group date">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id='calendarioActividad'><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>         
                </section>
                <!-- /.content -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('#calendarioActividad').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        });    
    </script>   

</body>
```

Comment: En donde te arroja el error? Porque veo un datepicker sin el tag `<script>`

Comment: Tienes razón, fue un error al transcribir el código aquí. Ya lo incorporé. El error se genera cuando en el combo select, selecciono SÍ, en ese momento se ejecuta:

                    }else{
                        $('#calendarioActividad').attr("disabled",false);
                        $('#calendarioActividad').datepicker("setDate", new Date());
                    }

y entiendo que al referenciar datepicker, no lo encuentra y marca el error